# Adding users to a directory recursively windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, permissions, users, cacls

I'm trying to set up my site on IIS, and it would seem I need to add the user group "USERS" to all files/folders within my site. This would require recursively adding a user to the root directory of my site. After some searching this is the closest command I can find: CACLS /T ... but this looks to be for setting permissions only. Does anyone know how to work it to add users? Or a more appropriate command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for windows 7 you should be using icacls, Both cacls and icacls works with either users or groups

```
icacls "C:\My\ISS\Path" /grant "USERS":R /T
```

Comment: Awesome sauce my friend, this worked like a charm!